# How to test whether I can typecast a dynamic to certain types or not in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, casting, option-type

I work with a web API where some of the endpoints return pure array (e.g. started with "["). But in case of that request produce errors, they will suddenly fallback to return a map (e.g. started with "{") with the fields explaining the error message.

How can I check whether I can typecast successfully to a type? For example, at Swift, we have `as?`, which means if a typecast failed, the operation will return null safely without raising an exception (with the side effect of wrapping the resulting object with optional). I need a way to test whether a typecast can be successfully performed on a data or not, but I can't afford that operation to rely on try-catch (means, I prefer that the operation can fail safely and return null for example, without raising an exception which I need to catch with try-catch block). How can I do that in Flutter?

Comment: in such cases always read `"A tour of the Dart language"`: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators

Comment: @pskink so let me confirm. If the runtime data type is `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`, will the operation `data is Map` returns `true`?

Comment: check it, try it, do it by yourself, a hint: just below the table they say: *"The result of obj is T is true if obj implements the interface specified by T. For example, obj is Object is always true."*